# How do I handle null value returned by a query for fields with no value in them and datatype as integer

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a table to which I had to add to fields of datatype integer, recently.
I use hibernate and my database in `PostgreSQL`.
My query to get the object corresponding to the table now returns null for the fields that were recently added. I am trying to check if they are null and to set `0` if the value is null.
I am unable to find a way to do this....can anybody help....
The hibernate query returns a pojo corresponding to my table and I want to check if one of the attributes in that pojo is `null`, but that attribute is  an integer, and that is my trouble.

Comment: If the value in database can be NULL, the corresponding field in the entity must be of type Integer, not int. An int can't be null. And null and 0 are two very different things.

Comment: yes, it is integer, but now I get a null pointer exception due to this .I need to check if that integer contain null , and I am trying to figure out a solution...thanks

Comment: This sounds like a side-effect of using `Integer` instead of `int`. Why not use `int` in your POJO so that nulls don't get into your database? It seems like you're interpreting nulls as 0 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it `0` if null then you just can give this value in the declaration,

```
Integer a=0;
```

If you use annotation then use can try default value. like

```
@Column(name="col_name", columnDefinition=" default '0' ")
```

Another way can be the setter method, If the field is private and you have public setter method then check null in that setter

```
public void setA(Integer a)
{
    if(a==null)
    {
        this.a=0;
    }else this.a=a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `int` in your POJO instead of `Integer`. This way `null` doesn't get into the database. If you *have* to use `Integer`, make sure you give it an initial value of `0`, and if you have any setters, ensure you check that the incoming argument is not `null`.

So either do:

```
public class MyPOJO {

    private int intVal = 0;
    ...
}
```

or:

```
public class MyPOJO {

    private Integer intVal = 0;

    ...

    public void setIntVal(Integer intVal) {
        if(intVal != null) {
            this.intVal = intVal;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers like setting nullable=true and columnDefinition=" default '0' " but nothing seemed to work. So I altered the default value of the column as 0, this resolved the issue.

NOTE: Please be careful about possible loss of information while modifying the default value.